# Refactoring the class component of submitted parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following pattern is encountered:

```
params[:vehicle][:user_id]
params[:location][:user_id]
params[...etc...][:user_id]
```

what syntax allows the creation of a method that inputs the current class as the symbol within the param ? for example

```
class VehiclesController

def edit
  v = Vehicle.where('user_id = ? AND user_id = ?', params[:vehicle][:user_id], current_user.id).first
end

class LocationsController

def edit
  l = Location.where('user_id = ? AND user_id = ?', params[:location][:user_id], current_user.id).first
end
```

Comment: `params[:vehicle][:user_id]` on its own doesn't do much. Can you give a little more context? How is each expression used? Also, what do you mean by _"creation of a method"_? There are method calls, but no methods are created in your code.

Comment: question amended.

Comment: So you want to get the symbol `:vehicle` from the class `Vehicle`? Maybe `Vehicle.name.downcase.to_sym`?

Comment: yes, but in an agnostic manner, where it picks up the controller's invoked class.  It seems awkward to state `params[class.name.downcase.to_sym]` but maybe that's it?

Comment: That's why I asked for more context :-) In your example there is no controller. Can you give a more complete example so it becomes clear what you are trying to do? (or maybe two examples so we can see the repetition that you are trying to avoid)

Comment: amendment provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a method to *ApplicationController*:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  private

  def form_params
    params[controller_name.singularize]
  end
end
```

and use it in other controllers:

```rb
class VehiclesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    form_params # => #<ActionController::Parameters {"user_id"=>"1"} permitted: false>
  end
end
```

For permitted params, could be this:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  private

  def form_params
    params.require(controller_name.singularize).permit(permitted_params)
  end

  def permitted_params
    [] # nothing is permitted by default
  end
end

class VehiclesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    form_params # => #<ActionController::Parameters {"user_id"=>"1"} permitted: true>
  end

  private

  # Override `permitted_params`
  def permitted_params
    # FIXME: Seems `user_id` is not needed when you have `current_user.id`.
    #        Besides, it is bad to expose current `user_id` in the form, 
    #        because I can start messing with it and start submitting 
    #        different ids in your forms; like a payment form, make someone  
    #        else pay for my charges.
    [:user_id]
  end
end
```